# Why the original data is mutated in this simple task?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know that data is immutable in redux and always should be, but i am faced with a weird problem may be i am not seeing the big picture.

This simple app just has a select box that change cats images, clicking a cat image should increment number of clicks below it so each cat should have its own number of clicks.

The app works very well but i do not understand something here:

In imageContainer component, logging `props.cats` is the same with logging the original data (cats). Both returns the modified cats objects with modified clickCount that is incremented after clicking the images.

I can not understand how the original data was affected in this process despite i am returning new data every time by reducers without mutating the state!!

My initial data:

```
import images from './images';
const cats =  [
  {
    name: 'Lucy',
    src: images.cat1,
    clickCount: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'Julia',
    src: images.cat2,
    clickCount: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Kattie',
    src: images.cat3,
    clickCount: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Hend',
    src: images.cat4,
    clickCount: 0,
  }
];

 export default cats;
```

First reducer:

```
import cats from '../cats'

export default (state = cats, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return cats.map(cat => cat.name === action.name ? {...cat, clickCount: ++cat.clickCount} : cat);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Second reducer:

```
import cats from '../cats'

export default (state = cats[0], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_CURRENT_CAT':
      return cats.filter(cat => cat.name === action.name)[0];
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

My components:

First Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import cats from '../cats';

const ImageContainer  = props =>{
  const {currentCat, incrementClicks} = props;
  console.log(props.cats)//cats with modified clickCount
   console.log(cats)     // cats with modified clickCounts
  return(
   <div className="img-cont">
     <img 
       src={currentCat.src}
       className="cat-img"
       onClick={() => incrementClicks(currentCat.name)}
       alt='cat_img'
     />
     <div className="clicks-count">
       <p>{currentCat.clickCount} clicks</p>
     </div>
   </div>
  );

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
   cats: state.cats,
   currentCat: state.currentCat,
 }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    incrementClicks: (name) => dispatch({
      type: 'INCREMENT',
      name
    })
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageContainer);
```

second component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import cats from '../cats';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const CatChanger = (props) => {

  return(
    <div className="cat-changer">
      <select onChange={(e) => {props.setCurrentCat(e.target.value)} }>    

        {cats.map((cat,i) => (
          <option value={cat.name} key={i}>{cat.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );

}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setCurrentCat: (name) => dispatch({
      type: 'SET_CURRENT_CAT',
      name
    })
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CatChanger);
```

So why the original data is mutated? or it is not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second reducer, you're getting the data from the `cats` import, instead of from the state! So your reduce is always returning an object from the import instead of from whatever state is passed in. You should not be importing `cats` in your reducer code.

Similarly in your first reducer, you are returning data from the cats import.

In both cases, you should be returning data from the `state` parameter passed in, not from the `cats` import.

Your first reducer would then look like this:

```
export default (state = cats, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state.map(cat => cat.name === action.name ? {...cat, clickCount: cat.clickCount + 1} : {...cat});

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Second reducer:

```
export default (state = cats[0], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_CURRENT_CAT':
      return {...state.filter(cat => cat.name === action.name)[0]};
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Note that the reducer body code references `state`, not `cats`.**
Also note that the reducers now return new objects that are clones of the objects in state (NOT the original objects), using the object spread operator:  `{...cat}` and `{...state.filter()[0]}`.

It's not necessarily a problem to import `cats` and use it as the default, though it's not the best design. (The problem is that the code isn't using the state parameter at all, and is instead using the imported object collection.) To avoid using the cats import in the reducers entirely, one option is to pass them in as the default store contents to `createStore`:

```
import cats from '../cats';
const defaultState = { cats, currentCatName: 'Lucy' };

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  defaultState
);
```

Then the defaults for the reducer parameters should return an empty array for the first reducer:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
```

and an empty object for the second reducer:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
```

Another alternative is to add a `LOAD_CATS` action that populates your cat collection, perhaps dispatched on componentDidMount for your top level app component.

Another optimization that will help avoid using existing objects is to change SET_CURRENT_CAT to simply change the cat name/id stored in the state:

```
export default (state, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_CURRENT_CAT':
          return action.name;
```

Then to get the current cat, you can add a selector that gets the cat by name/id from the state returned by the first reducer. (Adding an id field helps you handle the scenario where there are multiple cats with the same name.) The selector might look like this:

```
function getCatByName(state, name) { return state.cats.filter(cat => cat.name === name) }
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to avoid that?? my logic went for this way....What is the difference between your code and mine, still you depend on cats import!!

Comment: I still do not understand why state is mutated, i am returning new array of objects every time after dispatching, this should keep the original data safe,...

i tried to copy cats import into a new object and use it as
a initial state but still the problem, i am really confused!!

Comment: The array is new, but the objects in it are the original objects. Your code needs to clone the Cat objects. In JS objects are passed by reference.

Comment: Also, since your reducers are ignoring the state parameter, your state will always revert to the default state every time the reducer is called. And the default state contains the original objects from the import.

Comment: yes i know that objects are passed by reference so why i tried to create a new object by es7 object spread operator and Object.assign,... this did not work still cats is modified despite i am passing a totally new object!!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. Where are you passing a totally new object? In which lines of code?

Comment: as the initial state in the reducers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182558/discussion-between-stone-and-saher-elgendy).

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating state when you use the ++ operator on it. Use a simple addition instead

```
 return cats.map(cat => cat.name === action.name ? {...cat, clickCount: cat.clickCount + 1} : cat);
```

Comment: i used addition but it did not increment any thing..this is another part i can not understand

Surprisingly
      cat.clickCount + 1  does not work

      cat.clickCount++ works

Also i can not understand your point, how can increment mutate the state and addition not???